# PyCharm can't find module

Tags: pycharm

I have a project setup with directory structure

FOLDER1
...FOLDER2
......test.py
...FOLDER3
......FOLDER4
..........test2.py

Both FOLDER2 and FOLDER3 are marked as source folder.  From test.py I'm trying to import test2.  I tried

from FOLDER3.FOLDER4 import test2

but I get an error-  no module named FOLDER4.  How can I include this in pycharm?

I an't change the directory structure or code as it's from a repository that I can't edit.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import something from a folder e.g. you have a file called "test.py" in your folder "Test" then you just do

```
from Test.test import *
```

the * references everything that is in this python file. There you can specify attributes or classes you want to import.

Comment: This did not help.

Answer (score 0):

You could link to it outside of something like an enclosing file, so instead of starting with a

```
/subfolder/filename.extension
```

You could do the complete file path.
Cheers!